# What expression describes a person who knowlingly invests in a scam?

Tags: nouns, phrase-requests, adjectives

What word or phrase describes a person who invests in an enterprise that he knows is a scam or Ponzi scheme? Can the word or phrase refer to a person who votes for a politician who repeatedly tells known lies?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Who other than an idiot would do that? Have you seen such a person? Describe him/her in more detail with an example sentence where the word would be used. Otherwise, your question will be closed as off-topic. The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: *Can the word or phrase refer to a person who votes for a politician who repeatedly tells known lies?* In the US, the technical term for such a person is *Republican*.

Comment: @Rathony I think those other-than-idiots might be people who invest early in MLMs, in US penny stocks, and so on.  They buy but don't expect to hold.

Comment: @deadrat But they knew they could cheat others and make a fortune. I like your first comment, but some might not agree. :-)

Comment: @Rathony Yes, they saw an opportunity for cheating, so perhaps *invest* has the wrong connotation for my comment.  As for my first comment:  Oh, dear!  Did I write that out loud?  A more neutral statement might be "the technical term is *voter*."

Comment: You see,  it's not necessary to post a language [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311381/donald-trumps-run-on-sentences#comment703921_311381) about Trump to incite sarcastic, and totally unrelated political comments, even a  question about pyramid schemes can be a source of inspiration. Is this a taster of what we are  in for until November?